# deleting item from database table using id in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so i have this code :

```
echo "<h1>Books</h1>";
        echo "<table cellpadding=5 border=1>";
            echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Year</th><th>Deleting</th></tr>";
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$value['title']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['author']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['year']."</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='button' id='".$value['id']."' value='delete' name='delete'></td></tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
```

and i am using this for deleting it from my database:

```
 if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
           $deleted = $_GET['id'];
            $new ="DELETE FROM `book`.`book` WHERE `book`.`id` = $deleted;";
            $dbh->query($new);
        }
```

I am using PDO as a connection string to mysql database. In database i have ID,Title,Author,Year columns.

So what happens is, when i click on newly formed table with button "delete" nothing happens. 
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to do something about that sql injection?

Comment: You're using a `<button>` instead of `<a>` element. Basics of HTML. You also have sql injection possible there. Basics of PHP and SQL interaction.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using `type="button"`, it will not submit the form.

Use `type="submit"` to submit the form with the button tag, then set `$value['id']` as the `value=""` :

```
echo "<td><button type='submit' value='".$value['id']."' name='delete'>Delete</button</td></tr>";
```

If you haven't set it yet, make sure that the `<form>` tag wraps the `<table>` and has a `method` type that corresponds to your PHP:

```
<form method="GET">
```

And since you're using PDO, why not use prepared statements:

```
if(isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $deleted = $_GET['delete'];
    $new ="DELETE FROM `book`.`book` WHERE `book`.`id` = :id";
    $delete = $dbh->prepare($new);
    $delete->bindParam(':id', $deleted, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $delete->execute();
}
```

<sub>Assuming you're already connected.</sub>

Comment: Ghost: Stack's advocate for prepared statements ;)

Comment: Upvotes for PDO example, because you posted a complete solution.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there's no reason not to use it, its PDO anyways :)

Comment: Exactly. Like they say: "Use it, or lose it." ;)